# Creating small-collapsed notification in Android

Tags: android, android-notifications

I would like to create a notification for my Foreground service which is as small as possible.

Preferably like the one that Android creates for charging via USB:

[image: example notification]

**Anyone knows a way to configure `NotificationBuilder` (or `NotificationChannel`?) so that the notification is "collapsed" and tiny by default?**

Comment: You don't have direct control over that. Set your priority/importance low, and you should get that result in stock Android. However, the rendering of notifications is up to the version of Android and device manufacturers, and there is no requirement for a notification to appear in any particular size.

Comment: Unfortunately not a single `importance` value causes this result on a stock android (stock Pixel 1) for me... Thanks for taking the time to give me a hint.

Comment: Make sure you do a full uninstall/reinstall of your app, as the channel settings will not change from your previous values otherwise.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Starting Android P, If you set `NotificationChannel` priority to `IMPORTANCE_LOW`. This makes the Service notification to a single line.

```
final NotificationChannel systemChannel = new NotificationChannel(
        KEY_NOTIF_CHANNEL_SYSTEM,
        getString(R.string.title),
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
    );
```